# How to identify the first paragraph in a body of text in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a model which has a simple string which is an article in simple html.  An example of the data that is in this field is:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
>
> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
>
> Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

The database record has the appropriate opening and closing paragraph html markup between each paragraph.

I'm displaying this text with a simple:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.Article)
```

Is it possible to seperate out the first paragraph in my text?  My goal is twofold:

1. To use the first paragraph as an abstract on the index page, (as opposed to using a truncate method or seperate Abstract property)
2. To add an image between the first and second paragraphs.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can't you add an image between these paragraphs just while just storing in database.

Comment: I am not an mvc guy. Just an idea: you can add a property in your model say `ArticleAbstract` which returns the first element of `Article.Split(Environment.NewLine)` and another property which returns the second element. Now use `@Html.Raw(Model.ArticleAbstract)` to render abstract; then put img tag; then `@Html.Raw(Model.ArticleRest)` to render second para. (As Models are normally `partial` you can always add more properties)

Comment: Hi Bhustan - yes, but that doesn't help with getting an abstract - it also makes the creation of an article slightly more complicated for the users

Comment: Hi mshayem, the only problem with this approach is that there will be multiple newlines throughout the text - how to I split on just the first?

Comment: If the abstract has no new line inside it, `Article.Split(Environment.NewLine).First()` should do it. Otherwise you will have to define how you consider an _abstract_. The rest(except abstract) can be extracted with: `string.Join(Environment.NewLine,Article.Split(Environment.NewLine).Skip(0))`

Comment: *should be `Skip(1)` instead of `Skip(0)`

Comment: Having a few problems with your approach, the split syntax isn't working for me - I've posted an update.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, with the help of mshsayem, I managed to get the abstract the following way:

```
        string[] stringSeparators = new string[] { "</p><p>" };
        string[] result = article.Body.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None);
        string abstract = result[0];
```

Still having problems injecting the image between the first and second paragraphs though